# The problem that occur is that user can log in successfully but it does not show student details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a task in which I have student controller which have data in it but one can only see that data when he/she will be logged in.The problem that occur is that user can log in successfully but it does not show student details.

After log in it just display login signup again.Not the student info which I want.

user controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(signup svm)
    {
        signup s = db.signup.Where(a => a.email == svm.email && a.password == svm.password).SingleOrDefault();
        if(s!=null)
        {
            //return View("../Students/Index");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Students");

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.msg = "Invalid Email or Password";

        }
    }
```

Student controller

```
[Authorize]
public class StudentsController : Controller
{
    private DB db = new DB();

    // GET: Students
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Students.ToList());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like the user is never authorized so when the user hits the action marked with [Authorize] attribute he/she get redirect back to the login page. Is there any more code in the Login action? simply checking email-password pair's existence then redirect doesn't mean the user is being authenticated.

Comment: so what can i do to authorize user so user can see details

Comment: You are indeed not authenticating correctly. You are checking the password and then moving on. This is not enough. Maybe this link helps? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1105184/ASP-NET-MVC-Building-Your-First-Web-Application-Pa

Comment: yes i have found the issue just add this line to my code                 FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(s.email, true); and know every thing is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the Object 's' with the return statement.

Use other overloads of RedirectToAction which takes the Page,Controller,null,Object
Or Overload of RedirectToAction which takes Page,Controller,Object.

If You want to show all the records in students table,Then

Create a Session so You'll be a Authorised till the WebSite holds.